# What kind of damage is in this attic wall?

Tags: attic, damage

We were looking at a house to buy and one of the walls in the attic was damaged as shown in the picture below.

The house was the middle of three terraced houses so this particular wall was shared with the house next to it.

We ended up passing on the house because of an overeager other buyer.

I am curious as to what kind of damage this looks like and if it would have been expensive to fix.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide any more information? What material is the sheet good? What are those 3 rectangles? Why does it look like it isn't it flush to the rest of the wall?

Comment: I'd guess a fireplace/chimney above, given the forward thrust of the concrete and the mysterious doors (ash cleanout, base of flue cleanouts for auxiliary flues?) as well as how common leaks around a masonry chimney are, but that's based on wild guessing from almost no data, so...

Comment: I agree with Ecnerwal, a leak every now and then may not cost anything to fix or it could be a tough one. But I see no damage just an old stain. The ceiling looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like, *but may not be*,  water staining on concrete which in and of itself is not damage per-say.

But it raises the question of  how and why did water get to it and what water damage **may or may not be** in the non-concrete construction part of the house above it.

I would **guess** a roof leak around where this concrete exits the roof or compromise in the concrete itself above the roof line.

**No way to know about the cost of repairs** until one knows the extent of damage, if any, to the rest of the house.